# PyTorch custom loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

How should a custom loss function be implemented ? Using below code is causing error :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.utils.data as data_utils
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

num_epochs = 20

x1 = np.array([0,0])
x2 = np.array([0,1])
x3 = np.array([1,0])
x4 = np.array([1,1])

num_epochs = 200

class cus2(torch.nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(cus2,self).__init__()
    
    def forward(self, outputs, labels):
        # reshape labels to give a flat vector of length batch_size*seq_len
        labels = labels.view(-1)  

        # mask out 'PAD' tokens
        mask = (labels >= 0).float()

        # the number of tokens is the sum of elements in mask
        num_tokens = int(torch.sum(mask).data[0])

        # pick the values corresponding to labels and multiply by mask
        outputs = outputs[range(outputs.shape[0]), labels]*mask

        # cross entropy loss for all non 'PAD' tokens
        return -torch.sum(outputs)/num_tokens


x = torch.tensor([x1,x2,x3,x4]).float()

y = torch.tensor([0,1,1,0]).long()

train = data_utils.TensorDataset(x,y)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train , batch_size=2 , shuffle=True)

device = 'cpu'

input_size = 2
hidden_size = 100 
num_classes = 2

learning_rate = .0001

class NeuralNet(nn.Module) : 
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes) : 
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size , hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size , num_classes)

    def forward(self, x) : 
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
        
for i in range(0 , 1) :
        
        model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes).to(device)
        
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
#         criterion = Regress_Loss()
#         criterion = cus2()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        
        total_step = len(train_loader)
        for epoch in range(num_epochs) : 
            for i,(images , labels) in enumerate(train_loader) : 
                images = images.reshape(-1 , 2).to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                
                outputs = model(images)
                loss = criterion(outputs , labels)
                
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
#                 print(loss)
                
        outputs = model(x)
        
        print(outputs.data.max(1)[1])
```

makes perfect predictions on training data :

```
tensor([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Using a custom loss function from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181129040718/https://cs230-stanford.github.io/pytorch-nlp.html):

[image: image of the code used for the cus2 class]

is implemented in above code as `cus2`

Un-commenting code `#         criterion = cus2()` to use this loss function returns :

```
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

A warning is also returned :

> UserWarning: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. This will be an error in
> PyTorch 0.5. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python
> number

I've not implemented the custom loss function correctly ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your loss function is programmatically correct except for below:

```
    # the number of tokens is the sum of elements in mask
    num_tokens = int(torch.sum(mask).data[0])
```

When you do `torch.sum` it returns a 0-dimensional tensor and hence the warning that it can't be indexed. To fix this do `int(torch.sum(mask).item())` as suggested or `int(torch.sum(mask))` will work too.

Now, are you trying to emulate the CE loss using the custom loss? If yes, then you are missing the `log_softmax`

To fix that add `outputs = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(outputs, dim=1)` before  statement 4. Note that in case of tutorial that you have attached, `log_softmax` is already done in the forward call. You can do that too.

Also, I noticed that the learning rate is slow and even with CE loss, results are not consistent. Increasing the learning rate to 1e-3 works well for me in case of custom as well as CE loss.

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

Here are a few examples of custom loss functions that I came across in [this Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch/comments). It provides implementations of the following custom loss functions in `PyTorch` as well as `TensorFlow`.

[**Loss Function Reference for Keras & PyTorch**](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch/comments)

I hope this will be helpful for anyone looking to see how to make your own custom loss functions.

- [Dice Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Dice-Loss)
- [BCE-Dice Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#BCE-Dice-Loss)
- [Jaccard/Intersection over Union (IoU) Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Jaccard/Intersection-over-Union-(IoU)-Loss)
- [Focal Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Focal-Loss)
- [Tversky Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Tversky-Loss)
- [Focal Tversky Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Focal-Tversky-Loss)
- [Lovasz Hinge Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Lovasz-Hinge-Loss)
- [Combo Loss](https://www.kaggle.com/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch#Combo-Loss)

Comment: @blue-sky Perhaps your need has been long-served. However, I found this resource with a list of custom loss functions and thought of sharing. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use torch functions you should be fine

```py
import torch 

def my_custom_loss(output, target):
    loss = torch.mean((output-target*2)**3)
    return loss

# Forward pass to the Network
# then, 
loss.backward()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the return value of function should get smaller?